# Why use a reference to get a *char? Isn't better to not use references when we are using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

(I will have a set of questions at the end)When i have to create a function that takes a pointer `const char*` as example, i never use a reference because i thought it makes no sense to use a reference to a pointer. But in a book (C++ Primer Fifht Edition) the author tell us that we have to create out version of a funcition called `compare` to compare our c-style string so we avoid using the general template version

```
template <>
int compare(const char* const &p1, const char* const &p2)
{ return strcmp(p1, p2); }
```

Yes he's actually declaring that the pointers are const. And, the author actually write another function that only takes string literals

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
int compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M]);
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is he using a reference to get a pointer? Copy a pointer or take a reference are equally expensive, isn't it?
2. Can't the first version take string literals?
3. Why is he using a template for a function that does not require template paremeters? He is trying to overload another template funcion put thats not enought reason, is it?

Comment: That doesn't look like the right syntax. It should be `template <> int compare<something here>`, not just `template <> int compare`. The second one should probably also say `compare<something here>` instead of just `compare`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is he using a reference to get a pointer? Copy a pointer or take a reference are equally expensive, isn't it?

I am guessing that there is a function template:

```
template <typename T>
int compare(T const &t1, T const &t2) { ... }
```

and it is used elsewhere in the code base.

To make a specialization of the template for `char const*`, you'll have to use:

```
template <>
int compare(char const* const &p1, char const* const &p2) { ... }
 //         <--  T  -->
```

> Can't the first version take string literals?

Yes, it can.

> Why is he using a template for a function that does not require template paremeters? He is trying to overload another template funcion put thats not enought reason, is it?

That's the syntax for specializing a function template. It can be a function overload instead of a function template *only if* the function is called without explicitly specifying the template parameter.

If you define

```
int compare(char const* const &p1, char const* const &p2) { ... }
```

it won't be called when the caller uses `compare<char const*>(s1, s2)`.
It will be called when the callers uses `compare(s1, s2)`.

Comment: The first one can take string literals, but it probably won't, because there'll probably be a more specific instantiation of the template that beats it.

Comment: Tthe last 2 answers are good, but about the first one: why did he use a reference? wasn't `char const* const p1` enought?

Comment: @AlexeyAndreikin: That wouldn't have matched the template they wanted to specialize.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreikin, see the small update about the function template specialization.

Comment: Well, i will guess that the reference is there so it can take rvalues like a `const T&` does. There you go